# Why python allows the implementation of the abstract methods in the base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why Python allows the abstract methods to be implemented in the abstract base class when they are meant to be overridden by the derived class anyway?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod



class AbstractClassExample(ABC):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        print("Some implementation!")
        
class AnotherSubclass(AbstractClassExample):

    def do_something(self):
        super().do_something()
        print("The enrichment from AnotherSubclass")
        
x = AnotherSubclass()
x.do_something()
```

Comment: A Python function has to have a body.  That's a rule.  The "abstractmethod" thing is a library add-on.  It's not part of the core language.  For what it's worth, C++ allows exactly the same thing -- a pure abstract method is allowed to have a body.

Comment: has to have a body? but I can just get away with writing 'pass' statement in the function body

Comment: Lots of languages have abstract classes that can have some concrete methods. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Sure, "pass" is a body, just as useful as the body you have above.  Surely there are more important things to worry about.

Comment: @madhur In this case `pass` **is** the body.

Comment: Also, why are we even allowed to implement the abstract method when it is meant to be overridden by the derived classes? Can you give me an example where it would be useful for the abstract method to have a body in the abstract class?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Isn't concrete method different from an abstract method ? because abstract method need to be overridden by the sub class whereas the concrete method don't need to be overridden by the sub class.